# group by without aggregate function and get one value from it

Tags: sql-server, database, group-by

This query returns error like it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT SPEC_VALUE,SPEC_SKU 
FROM spec 
     join specdb on specdb_tech_no = SPEC_TECH_NO
WHERE SPEC_TECH_NO = '20081'
```

This returns

```
1   0035862
2   0051197
2   0063493
2   0013372
2   0089991
3   0087134
4   0002602
5   0002041
5   0002042
5   0002050
5   0002044
5   0024315
6   0085601
6   0090337
7   0002789
7   0002790
7   0002791
```

Now I want query should return first group by value like

```
1   0035862
2   0051197
3   0087134
4   0002602
5   0002041
6   0085601
7   0002789
```

I tried

```
SELECT SPEC_VALUE,SPEC_SKU
FROM spec
     JOIN specdb on specdb_tech_no = SPEC_TECH_NO
WHERE SPEC_TECH_NO = '20081'
GROUP BY spec.SPEC_VALUE
```

But it shows error:

> "it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause."

i used distinct but it also shows errors.

Comment: Distinct is almost never a proper solution. One solution is to use aggregate function, like `min(SPEC_SKU) as SPEC_SKU`.

Comment: You don't have an ORDER BY clause so with just those 2 columns first value doesn't make sense.

Comment: You won't be able to select that unlees you have some ordering column to tell engine which value you want from duplicates per group.

Comment: There is no prober solution to your question as it stands, @Vinnie's answer(though incorrect) is currently the closest you can get, but it will not provide the answer you are requesting. You can't pick the first value, since the term "first value" is data from an arbitrary row. You need something to order by something. If you have an autoincremented id column in the table, this could be solved

Answer (score 1):

This Error is Telling you that on what basis i(SQL Server) performed Group By Operation on **Spec_Value**?in Your Case **Spec_sku** is Not Contained any Aggregate Function and it is not in **Group by** Clause.

Either you want to select one specific value (e.g. the **MIN**, **SUM**, or **AVG**) in which case you would use the appropriate aggregate function or you want to select every value as a new row (i.e. including **Spec_sku**  in the GROUP BY field list).But in Our Case i.e not our Requirement and Note That you can't use **TOP** Function for Spec_sku Column with Group By Clause.

**So According to output Requirement Try This Code once**:

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT SPEC_VALUE,SPEC_SKU, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SPEC_VALUE ORDER BY SPEC_VALUE) AS rn
FROM spec as s
     JOIN specdb as sd on s.tech_no  = Sd.TECH_NO
WHERE S.TECH_NO = '20081')

select SPEC_VALUE,SPEC_SKU from cte where rn=1
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
SPEC_VALUE  SPEC_SKU
1           0035862
2           0051197
3           0087134
4           0002602
5           0002041
6           0085601
7           0002789
```

Comment: This is the same incorrect select as in ricky89's answer. One morning you can discover that surprisingly your select selects different values. The order is not guarantied.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to use the min function on SKU for each SPEC returned:

```
SELECT SPEC_VALUE
,MIN(SPEC_SKU)
FROM spec
JOIN specdb 
ON specdb_tech_no = SPEC_TECH_NO
WHERE SPEC_TECH_NO = '20081'
GROUP BY spec.SPEC_VALUE
```

Comment: `2   0051197` this is not min. OP wants `first` row per group but he doesn't know that it is impossible with cols he provided.

Comment: If he doesn't know it's impossible, isn't it useful to illustrate to him what is possible?  He needs to aggregate on any column that's not in the group by, but it's clear that's a new concept.  Why don't you let the OP answer before you comment AND downvote?

Comment: I already know without OP that your query will return `2   0013372` but he wants `2   0051197`, so this is incorrect answer.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want the first instance of each, you could use partition by as below:

```
SELECT * FROM(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SPEC_VALUE ORDER BY SPEC_VALUE DESC) AS ROWNUMBER,
SPEC_VALUE,
SPEC_SKU
FROM @temp) AS t1
WHERE t1.ROWNUMBER = 1
```

You can play around with the above to get different results sets.

Comment: `2   0051197` this is not max. OP wants first row per group but he doesn't know that it is impossible with cols he provided.

Comment: Well given I am not trying to return the max values, I would expect not. The result set from the above gives what the op is after (ie the first row for each SPEC_VALUE).

Comment: nope, that is not true. You can think that it will return first values but on other machine results may be different. You are ordering by constant.